# What is the "Tests" target under xcode5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

Please don't flame me here.  I've searched and can't find this.

Why does Xcode 5 add a second target with "Tests" at the end?  Example "myApp" and then "myAppTests".

Why do I want that?

I think I've deleted it in the past, but I'm annoyed that it adds it.  Is there an easy way to create new templates that are more like the old ones without it?

Answer (score 0):

It is for unit testing, I do not know if since Xcode 5 you are able to create a project without this target.

You might have a look over here : http://remotewhiteboard.com/blog/apps/how-to-delete-a-target-in-xcode-5/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I know how to delete targets. I've deleted this target before.  And I gathered that this was for unit testing, but I don't know what that is, why I want it, how it's better than testing the actual app, or why apple would force this in the project rather than making it an option.